# Avoid excessive complexity in Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net

I have dictionary that provide some string processing methods based on given `NWS enum` value:

```
 var nwsToStringConverters = new Dictionary<NWS, Func<MeteoParameter, string>>
            {
                {NWS.Unknown, intensity => "some string"},
                {NWS.Precipitation, intensity => AddIntensity("some string2", intensity, KindOfAdjective.Plural)},
                {NWS.FreezingRain, intensity => AddIntensity("some string3", intensity, KindOfAdjective.Masculine)},
                  //....more elements here

            };
```

`AddIntensity` is my processing method.
`KindOfAdjective` is my enum.
`MeteoParameter` is my DTO.

Code analysis warns me about CA1502.

However if change `intensity => AddIntensity(..)` to named functions it not warns me anymore. But for sure i dont need 30 methods, that difference only in 1 string constant. Any elegant way to solve this?

Comment: `[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Maintainability", "CA1502:AvoidExcessiveComplexity", Justification = "Meh")]`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski is right--cyclomatic complexity is a useful tool to help you notice when things are being unnecessarily complicated, but this dictionary declaration shouldn't impact cyclomatic complexity at all. I'm guessing there's a mistake with the way the code is being analyzed.